# Doctrine - Auto insert rows association table

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have 3 tables : Profile - Permission - ProfilePermissionValue

Profile and Permission are classic entities, and ProfilePermissionValue is an association of a Profile.id, Permission.id, and an extra field representing the  value of the permission for the profile.

When I add a Permission, I want a new row being inserted in ProfilePermissionValue for each Profile.
Same on reverse, when I add a new Profile, ... And same on delete by the way.

The question : Is there a way to do it with Doctrine (Symfony 3) functionalities, or I need to code it myself ?

Comment: Yes, is a many-to-many relationship with extra column : http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html

Comment: this is not really what i need, because orders have products or not, but my profiles need to have permanently all permissions which are true or not.

Comment: Which values can a ProfilePermissionValue entry have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you look at the permission <-> profile more strictly than you should. Basically in almost every [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) I worked with there was a assumption - when something is not allowed, it`s disallowed (or when something is not disallowed is allowed which is more dangerous). Which significantly reduce amount of data, you must save.

So when you create your entities like this

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Permission
{

    // id column

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;



    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

and

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User
{

    // id column

    // name column

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Permission::class)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="allowed_permissions",
     *        joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *        inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *    )
     * @var Permission[]|Collection
     */
    private $allowedPermissions;



    /**
     * @return Permission[]
     */
    public function getAllowedPermissions()
    {
        return $this->allowedPermissions->toArray();
    }

}
```

you can simply implement your own class for interface [AuthorizationCheckerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AuthorizationCheckerInterface.html) as

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class Authorizator implements AuthorizationCheckerInterface
{

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param User $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isGranted($name, $user)
    {
        foreach ($user->getAllowedPermissions() as $permission) {
            if ($permission->getName() === $name) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

without any needs of having deny permission in your database.